# Size AppBar title space to fit title

Tags: flutter

In our app, we have the ability for a user to enter their name, and we want to display a greeting with that name. Names can be very long, so we just want to limit how many lines the name can go onto, and then use the `Text` widget's `overflow: ...` and `maxLines: ...` to perform the string truncation.

The issue is that AppBars do not resize themselves to contain all of the text displayed. The result is the top/bottom of letters being trimmed off (especially the bottom loop of "g", for example).

I know about [`toolbarHeight`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/toolbarHeight.html) but we don't want to hardcode that. It should increase or decrease based on the vertical size needed for the title, which changes as the user interacts with our app.

Below I pasted a pruned-down version of the sample app provided on [the official AppBar page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html). The title has a fixed amount of vertical space, enough (in this example) for 2 lines but not 3.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [AppBar].

void main() => runApp(const AppBarApp());

class AppBarApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: AppBarExample(),
    );
  }
}

class AppBarExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Good morning, ghghghghghghghgghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghg',
          maxLines: 3
        ),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'This is the home page',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: appbar is just a statefulwidget class, with implementation of PreferedSizeWidget, this how they calculate it `AppBarTheme.of(context).toolbarHeight ?? kToolbarHeight) + (preferredSize.bottomHeight ?? 0` , you can always make your own, based on your need